# Wrong answers to simple math problems in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am getting wrong answers to simple math problems in excel 2010. Possibly related to rounding. How can I fix this?

Example: Calculator figures .77*32 as 24.64, Excel figures it as 24.60

Comment: From the looks of things it's just rounding them to 1 decimal place.

Comment: Do you get 24.60 or 24.6? Maybe it's just formatting results and showing 1 decimal place, but actual precision is better.

Comment: what are your cell format settings?

Comment: The only way I can get that result in Excel is to use a custom format along the lines of #0.0 or ##.# so that the last decimal place is rounded or ignored. Reformat the cell as a number with 2 decimal places and post back with the result

Comment: I just tested this and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

excel work with 8 byte numbers bydefault and have 15 digit presision. i was unable to duplicate your example in office 2010 for mac and windows version.

Most likely that you are looking at formatted numbers.  24.64/32=0.76865. Is your 0.77 not perhaps formatted already?